# Is every sigma algebra generated by some subclass.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ a non empty set and consider and $\cal{A}$ a sigma algebra in  $\Omega$. Is there always a set $\cal{C}\subset\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$, $\cal{C}$ strictly contained in  $\cal{A}$  such that 
$\cal{A}$ is generated by $\cal{C}?$

For example, is the Lebesgue measure generated by some $\cal{C}?$

**Obs.**
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87838/is-every-sigma-algebra-the-borel-algebra-of-a-topology

I have already seen the discussion in the above link, but I'm not asking noting special about the class  $\cal{C}$.

Also in the above case the answer is quite sophisticated. I'm wondering if in the question I ask the answer is more simple.

Comment: You had better put some condition on $\mathcal C$, otherwise just take $\mathcal A = \mathcal C$.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. When I ask the question I have the condition ${\cal C}$ strictly contained in ${\cal A}$ in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal A$, then you'll have a set that generates $\mathcal A$. If you want a smaller set, take $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{A}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$.